# What flash slideshow player can read an rss feed as a source?

Tags: rss, gallery

i would like to add a flash slideshow to my wordpress site, but do not want to manually add the pictures. I currently use nextgen to manage my galleries.

I have a page set up that shows the most recent pictures, and there is an rss feed available for this. (http://rapscallion.eu/category/gallery/)

What flash slideshow can use this rss feed as input? It would be beneficial if it had a wordpress plugin and some documentation?

Comment: Why must it be flash? There are some impressive slideshows and sliders in JQuery, and they work on all browsers mobile too! Flash limits you, and the trend in development is moving away from flash

Comment: *As-written*, this is a question about third-party scripts, not a **WordPress** question.

Answer (score 1):

### SlideShowPro is the best Flash slideshow player for WordPress

Back before it was "Un Cool" to use Flash I used a flash component called [SlideShowPro for Flash](http://slideshowpro.net/).  It is very extensible and uses an XML file to load the content into the slideshow.  It also allows you to customize all aspects of the display using Adobe Flash CS4 or CS5.

It also has the ability to auto load pictures from a Media RSS feed and there are a number of PHP scripts available out there that will generate the XML on the fly for any images added to a folder.

I just checked the website and they have brought the product along in the last year or so.  It is now generates slideshows for the iOs and Android mobile devices.

The slideshow player works with the [SlidePress WordPress Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/slidepress/screenshots/) and there is also the NextGEN Gallery [Slidepress XML Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nextgen-gallery-slidepress-xml/) which creates the proper XML file for your NextGen slideshows.

### [More information on using SlideShowPro with WordPress](http://slideshowpro.net/products/slideshowpro_player/#sspsa-slidepress)

Comment: halfway there. i have built a SlideShowPro slideshow (http://rapscallion.eu/slideshowpro/). That is using the slidepress plugin.

Comment: the next step is to link the rss feed.. scratches head!...